# Do sharks quickly respond to blood in the water?

Tags: biology, safety, sharks

This seems to be portrayed in movies and TV quite often: we find a group of travelers desperately stranded on a small boat or raft. For one reason or another someone becomes injured and blood is spilled into the seawater. Without fail (sometimes even *minutes* later) we find our hapless individuals surrounded by one or more hungry sharks.

Question -- Is a shark's ability to "smell" blood, or their numbers and vicinity, exaggerated here (and as such just a convenient plot device)? Or should I really expect at least one shark to arrive nearly every time, if ever in that situation myself?

Comment: Not lawyers blood.  Professional courtesy.

Comment: @geoffc:  I've heard that throwing a lawyer overboard will scare the sharks away.  ;-D

Comment: @RandolfRichardson - Unless he gets injured then they all swarm the richest person on the boat.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image: Shark Senses] <sup>[Image Source](http://www.time.com/time/specials/packages/article/0,28804,1996186_1996786_1996788,00.html)</sup>

To detect blood the smell first has to reach the shark.

From [The Naked Scientist](http://www.thenakedscientists.com/HTML/content/latest-questions/question/2110/):

> **Water molecules in general are carried to the shark by water currents**.
>
> If there are no water currents then it is molecular diffusion, the
> random movement of molecules that disperses the odour away from the
> source.
>
> **In general the travel time of odour depends entirely on the local
> water velocity**.
>
> Near the water surface **water velocities in the ocean
> can range between a few centimetres per second on a very calm day and
> several metres per second in a strong current**.

From the [ReefQuest Center for Shark Research](http://elasmo-research.org/education/white_shark/smell.htm):

> **A shark's lateral line system enables it to detect subtle water
> movements**. Therefore, when a shark's acute olfactory system detects an
> attractive chemical, all it needs to do is turn into the current.
> Sooner or later, this will bring a shark to the source of the odor.

---

From  [PBS - Jean-Michel Costeau Ocean Adventures](http://www.pbs.org/kqed/oceanadventures/episodes/sharks/indepth-senses.html):

> The notion that the mighty great white can smell blood from a great
> distance has been central to modern shark mythology.
>
> **They can detect some scents at concentrations as low as
> 1 part per 25 million**, which translates to about a third of a mile
> away in the open ocean.

From an [Interview](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/sharks/masters/myths.html) with shark expert [Samuel Gruber](http://www6.miami.edu/sharklab/):

> ***It comes down to the concentration of the stimulating chemical** at the
> nose's receptor cell that determines if an animal will detect a smell.
> **That level is parts per million in sharks.***

From the [American Museum of Natural History](http://www.amnh.org/learn/pd/sharks_rays/rfl_myth/myth_page5.html):

> **The lemon shark can detect tuna oil at one part per 25 million**--that's
> equivalent to about 10 drops in an average-sized home swimming pool.
>
> Other types of sharks can detect their prey at one part per 10
> billion; that's one drop in an Olympic-sized swimming pool!
>
> Some
> sharks can detect these low concentrations of chemicals at prodigious
> distances--up to several hundred meters (the length of several
> football fields)—depending on a number of factors, particularly the
> speed and direction of the water current.

From [Sharks of the Atlantic Research and Conservation Coalition (ShARCC)](http://atlanticsharks.org/biology_senses.php):

> **Some species are able to detect as little as one part per million of
> blood in seawater**.
>
> ... however, it is suggested that sharks are not stimulated by mammal blood (e.g. from humans) in the same way as they are by fish blood.

---

**More:**

- [Mythbusters - Shark Week: Drop of Blood](http://dsc.discovery.com/videos/shark-week-drop-of-blood.html)
- [The Straight Dope - How quickly can sharks detect blood in the water?](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2781/shark-youre-whats-for-dinner)
- [Time - Summer of the Shark](http://www.time.com/time/specials/packages/article/0,28804,1996186_1996786_1996788,00.html)

Answer (score 10):

Is it exaggerated? Sure.

Does it happen? Yes.

> It is recognized that most if not all species 
>   of sharks possess a keen sense of smell which is 
>   used in detecting dead and wounded prey or 
>   other edible material during their well-known 
>   scavenging operations. [...]  This tracking ability is 
>   well recognized by skin divers and fishermen 
>   who have involuntarily attracted sharks by retaining 
>   speared fish or by discarding trash fish 
>   and offal from their boats.

Source: Tester AL. 1963. [The role of olfaction in shark predation.](http://scholarspace.manoa.hawaii.edu/handle/10125/4935) Pac Sci 17(2): 145-170.

There's been plenty of [research](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jmor.10208/abstract) [on](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cne.901610110/abstract) [shark](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0300962972903696) [olfaction](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960982210005919).

There is a technique used in shark-fishing of dragging a "burley bag" or "burley bucket" of bait behind the boat to attract sharks. (I found lots of mentions on the web, but nothing particularly citable.)

Comment: add a cutout surfboard behind the "burley" and you can get quite spectacular jumps from the sharks (I remember from a nat geo channel documentory)